# Flutter can't display listview on real device, but it can on emulator

Tags: flutter, listview

i'm still learning in Flutter, i got something make me confused, so i want to display some listview (chat), i'm using `listview builder` in Flutter, and when i try it in Emulator (Android/IOS) it working perfectly, but when i try to publish it and try it in tester, the listview can't event be displayed (just blank at the listview section), but on other page, i use the same format of listview (with different data and style) it can be display, idk what is happening rn

here's my code:

```dart
Expanded(
              child:
                  // display list chat inside listview builder
                  ListView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: listChat.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15,
                        right: 15,
                        top: index == 0 ? 10 : 0,
                        bottom: 10),
                    child:
                        // check if listChat is empty, then display "Tidak ada chat"
                        listChat.isEmpty
                            ? Container(
                                // align center
                                alignment: Alignment.center,

                                // create chip center to tell the another user is joined the group
                                child: Chip(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                  side: const BorderSide(
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 239, 239)),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                  label: TextComp(
                                      text: "Tidak ada chat",
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                ),
                              )
                            : listChat[index]['jenis'] == "join"
                                ? Container(
                                    // align center
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,

                                    // create chip center to tell the another user is joined the group
                                    child: Chip(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                      side: const BorderSide(
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 239, 239, 239)),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                      label: TextComp(
                                          text: listChat[index]['nama'] == null
                                              ? "Seseorang telah bergabung"
                                              : listChat[index]['nama'] +
                                                  " telah bergabung",
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: listChat[index]
                                                      ['id_user'] ==
                                                  idUser
                                              ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                                              : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              child: TextComp(
                                                  text: listChat[index]
                                                              ['nama'] ==
                                                          null
                                                      ? "Seseorang"
                                                      : listChat[index]['nama'],
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                            ),
                                            listChat[index]['jenis'] == "Materi"
                                                ? Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            top: 0),
                                                    child: Chip(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Colors.grey[200],
                                                      side: const BorderSide(
                                                          color: Colors.teal),
                                                      shape:
                                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                              borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          100)),
                                                      label: TextComp(
                                                          text: listChat[index][
                                                                      'judul'] ==
                                                                  null
                                                              ? ""
                                                              : listChat[index]
                                                                  ['judul'],
                                                          fontSize: 10,
                                                          color: Colors.teal,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold,
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.left),
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                : Container(),
                                            ChipChat(
                                                onTap: () {},
                                                text: listChat[index]
                                                            ['isi_chat'] ==
                                                        null
                                                    ? ""
                                                    : listChat[index]
                                                        ['isi_chat'],
                                                jenis: listChat[index]['jenis'],
                                                choosen: true),
                                            // label to display listChat[index]['judul'] with background chip gray

                                            // container for date and time
                                            Container(
                                              child: TextComp(
                                                  text:
                                                      // convert timestamp to local time in format FF-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
                                                      Moment(DateTime.parse(
                                                                  listChat[
                                                                          index]
                                                                      [
                                                                      'timestamp'])
                                                              .toLocal())
                                                          .format('LLL'),
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

and here's my `ChipChat`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:kambiumgo/components/text.dart';

class ChipChat extends StatelessWidget {
  Function onTap;
  String text;
  String jenis;
  bool choosen;
  ChipChat(
      {super.key,
      required this.onTap,
      required this.text,
      required this.jenis,
      required this.choosen});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          onTap();
        },
        child: Container(
          // max width 80%
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 0, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(
              color: choosen
                  ? jenis == "Materi"
                      ? Colors.blueAccent
                      : Colors.teal
                  : Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 239, 239),
            ),
            color: choosen
                ? jenis == "Materi"
                    ? Colors.blueAccent
                    : Colors.teal
                : const Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 239, 239),
          ),
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              TextComp(
                text: text,
                fontSize: 14,
                color: choosen ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

i just didn't understand, why on the real device, the listview can't be display...

Comment: Generally, any scaling that is driven by device width is wrong. TL;DR: use LayoutBuilder (not MediaQuery) to determine breakpoints only (side nav vs bottom nav, two columns vs three). Then use Flex widgets (Row, Column, Expanded, Spacer, etc) to lay out your text. Do not change the font size.

Comment: That's strange, never seen this case. Maybe there's something relates to data differences from real devices & emulator. Tried to plug your real device & run flutter in it.

Comment: That top-level `Expanded`, what is its parent? If it's not a `Row` or `Column` that's most likely the problem. Debug builds are more forgiving with wrong use of `Expanded` but should still show errors in the console. Release builds will give layout errors like you encounter